# Using SQL result as a filter for another query

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

Here's my code and there's a thousand transaction_no result. Which is I have to use as a filter for another code with the same table.

```
select Item_Code, Transaction_No, Sales, Quantity
from `transaction_table`
where item_code = 'HTHP-P'
```

Comment: Please provide sample data, desired results, and a clear explanation of what you are doing.

Comment: Try `AND`. Multiple conditions.

Comment: hi @kyros, welcome to stackoverflow. your post nor the title does not really ask a question in its current shape. and also misses some details it seems like "is this your main query" or "is this your filter query". also make sure you copy-paste your code or make sure it is typo-free.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *could* use `in`, if you want to filter on the transactions:

```
select . . .
from `transaction_table` tt
where tt.transacton_no in (select tt2.Transaction_No
                           from `transaction_table` tt2
                           where tt2.item_code = 'HTHP-P'
                          );
```

If you want all rows for transactions that have the specified item, you can also use `qualify`:

```
select tt.*
from `transaction_table` tt
where 1=1
qualify countif(tt2.item_code = 'HTHP-P') over (partition by Transaction_No) > 0;
```

Comment: Thanks you, this helped me. I got this as a result. now I want to show the 'HTHP-P' On the first row as something like this. how can I do that?

Item_Code2 Item_Code transaction_no Sales Quantity
HTHP-P        SCARD-CLC 8748                  534           1
HTHP-P        WPL                 43169                  0           1
HTHP-Q        TG-R                 11135                  243.48   1
HTHP-Q        L888                 147006                  792.86   1
HTHP-Q        CH-SKL          67684                   0           1

Comment: @kyros . . . You need an `order by`.  If I understands correctly `order by transaction_no, (item_code = 'HTTP-P') desc`.

Answer (score 0):

You could use 'in' to filter using the results.

```
select Item_Code, Transaction_No, Sales, Quantity
from `transaction_table`
where Transaction_No in ( select t.Transaction_No from `transaction_table` t where t.item_code = 'HTHP-P')
```

or You could store all the results in a temp table and then use the results to filter later in another section of the code.

```
create table #temp
(
  Transaction_No varchar(30)
);
insert into #temp
select Transaction_No from `Tranaction_Table` where item_code = 'HTHP-P'
```